# Como detectar a navegação usando a classe WebBrowser e capturar informações com C#

Tags: c#, navegador-de-internet

Olá, estou fazendo uma integração com a API do Mercado livre, onde eu preciso abrir uma tela do navegador com a página para o usuário permitir o acesso à API da minha aplicação ([conforme a documentação aqui](https://developers.mercadolivre.com.br/pt_br/server-side/#Passo-a-passo)). Para fazer isso, eu pretendo aproveitar da classe `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` que abre o Internet Explorer na página que eu precisar.

Pelo metadata da classe, eu consigo utilizar o `event Navigated` passando um método que permitiria eu verificar a partir da URL do navegador se a página que eu passei como `redirect_url` é a que foi chamada (assim eu posso pegar o token de autenticação) assim:

```cs
public class Test
{
    public void requestCode()
    {
        var clientId = 123;                // algum clientId
        var redUrl = "https://www.foo.com" // minha url de redirect
        var url =
            $"https://auth.mercadolivre.com.br/authorization?"+
            $"response_type=code&" +
            $"client_id={clientId}&"+
            $"redirect_uri={redUrl}";
        try
        {
            using (var browser = new WebBrowser())
            {
                browser.Navigated += 
                    new WebBrowserNavigatedEventHandler(
                        requestAuthorizeOnNavigated
                    );
                browser.Navigate(url, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    public void requestAuthorizeOnNavigated(
        object sender, 
        WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e
    )
    {
        Console.Write(sender.ToString(), e.ToString());
    }
}
```

Quando eu rodo meu código, eu consigo abrir a página do mercado livre que gera o token (ou que pede ao usuário para autorizar inicialmente). O problema é que eu não estou conseguindo detectar a navegação, mesmo declarando o evento dentro do using...

O que preciso fazer para conseguir detectar a navegação (e ler a URI que for informada na última navegação) a partir desse exemplo?

Comment: Se usar o evento `DocumentCompleted` pode obter o URL a partir do parâmetro `e` que é do tipo `WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs`.

Comment: hmmm vou ver se consigo usar dessa forma... Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pra resolver meu problema eu tive que reformular minha aplicação para que se comportasse como uma webaplication e minha aplicação pudesse fazer uso de todos os recursos de soluções na web pois após o ML autenticar ele redireciona a requisição do usuário para a URL enviada no parâmetro `redirect_uri` que está descrito na documentação.

Comment: Leandro, mesmo utilizando o WebApplication (buscando pelo Response), o Token não é apresentado na resposta, o curioso é que quando chamo pelo Browser o TG retorna. Tem algum exemplo do caminho que seguiu?

Answer (score 0):

Compartilho aqui uma parte do código para acessar as chamadas no MCL, fonte: IntegracoesMercadoLivreAPISAPB1-master.zip (gitHub), más antes será necessário seguir estes passos para registrar a aplicação conforme link "https://developers.mercadolivre.com.br/pt_br/autenticacao-e-autorizacao":

```
    public void GetNewAccessToken()
    {
        var client = new RestClient("https://api.mercadolibre.com/oauth/token");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.AddParameter("undefined", "client_id=IdDaSuaAplicacaoNoMcl&client_secret=ClientSecretDaSuaAplicacaoNoMcl&grant_type=client_credentials", ParameterType.RequestBody);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

        var responseTokenObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccessToken>(response.Content);
```

//... passagem pelo objeto

}